# What to use to connect on AWS Aurora Serverless V2 using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

On the official [@aws-sdk/client-rds-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rds-data/index.html) documentation, it says:

> Amazon RDS provides an HTTP endpoint to run SQL statements on an
> Amazon Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster. To run these statements, you
> work with the Data Service API.
>
> The Data Service API isn't supported on Amazon Aurora Serverless v2 DB
> clusters.

But it does't point to another library to connect on a Serverless v2. Is it impossible with NodeJS?

Really appreciate any help

Comment: I saw [an example](https://www.serverlessguru.com/blog/how-to-set-up-aws-rds-proxy-with-iam-authentication-enabled-to-aurora-serverless-v2-cluster) for accessing Aurora Serverless v2 from NodeJS by means of RDS Proxy, but I cannot find any for accessing it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using simple driver to connect AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless V2 directly, code below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
dbconn  = mysql.createConnection({
                                  host: host,
                                  user: user,
                                  password: password,
                                  database: database,
                                  multipleStatements: true,
                                  connectionLimit: 10
                })
                
dbconn.query(sql, (err,result)=>{
                            if(err) {
                                console.log(err)
                                i_errors++;
                            } 
                            console.log(result);
                            
                           
                    }
                );
                
dbconn.end();
```